# Issue with firing an event inside window.setTimeout

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system

I am not able to find where i am doing wrong.

i have a parent component **A** with two child components **B** and **C**

my scenario is to fire an event in **window.setTimeout** of component **B** and send it to component **C**

```
    var PhaseVar = component.get('v.Phase');
    var PEvent = component.getEvent('pEvent');
    var delay= 6000;
    console.log('PhaseVar :'+PhaseVar ); // i am able to get value
     console.log('PEvent :'+PEvent ); // i am able to get value
    window.setTimeout(
    $A.getCallback(function(){
    var PhaseVar = component.get('v.Phase');
    var PEvent = component.getEvent('pEvent');
    console.log('PhaseVar :'+PhaseVar ); // returning null
    console.log('PEvent :'+PEvent ); // returning null

       pEvent.setParams({
                    'data':{
                        'Error':  'xxxxxx',
                        'Phase': 'yyyyy'

                    } 
                });
                console.log('event  : ');
                PEvent.fire(); // not working 
        }), delay
    );
```

If I try get any of the component related things like **attributes** or **events** inside the **timeout** i am getting null and if i keep out side the **timeout** unable to fire the event.

need help me in fixing this

Comment: you seem to have an extra closing brace? In JavaScript 80% issues could be caused by Indentation..

Comment: sorry i made changes, extra close brace might not be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass, `component` ,`PmtSrnEvent` and other variable to `setTimeout`. The reason being `setTimeout` runs in different context asyn and cant find the local variable to your function.

```
window.setTimeout(
    $A.getCallback(function(component , PmtSrnEvent){
    var PhaseVar = component.get('v.Phase');
    var PEvent = component.getEvent('pEvent');
    console.log('PhaseVar :'+PhaseVar ); // returning null
    console.log('PEvent :'+PEvent ); // returning null

       PmtSrnEvent.setParams({
                    'data':{
                        'Error':  'xxxxxx',
                        'Phase': 'yyyyy'

                    } 
                });
                console.log('event  : ');
                PEvent.fire(); // not working 
            }                
        }), delay , component , PmtSrnEventPmtSrnEvent
    );
```

Src: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32326721/pass-parameter-to-settimeout-callback-function/32326935

Comment: Hi Pranay, thank you for responding. i tried this already and i tried after you comment as well. i am getting Cannot read property 'get' of undefined.